# Spring controller parameter is being assumed instantiated but when/where was it instantiated?

Tags: java, spring

[Thymeleaf tutorial code](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm)

How is this SeedStarter getting instantiated?
See the method body shows interaction with an object SeedStarter..so how did it get instantiated in the first place?

Since this project is a tutorial, I will excerpt the exact place I've looked for answers. I am not CURRENTLY aware of any other way that this "guest" object could be created other than if:
1. It were previously created and added to the model. (No init in controller then probably isnt added to the model elsewhere)
2. A private member of the controller that was already created.

```
@RequestMapping({"/","/seedstartermng"})
    public String showSeedstarters(final SeedStarter seedStarter) {
        seedStarter.setDatePlanted(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        return "seedstartermng";
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@Controller
public class SeedStarterMngController {


    @Autowired
    private VarietyService varietyService;

    @Autowired
    private SeedStarterService seedStarterService;



    public SeedStarterMngController() {
        super();
    }



    @ModelAttribute("allTypes")
    public List<Type> populateTypes() {
        return Arrays.asList(Type.ALL);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("allFeatures")
    public List<Feature> populateFeatures() {
        return Arrays.asList(Feature.ALL);
    }

    @ModelAttribute("allVarieties")
    public List<Variety> populateVarieties() {
        return this.varietyService.findAll();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("allSeedStarters")
    public List<SeedStarter> populateSeedStarters() {
        return this.seedStarterService.findAll();
    }



    @RequestMapping({"/","/seedstartermng"})
    public String showSeedstarters(final SeedStarter seedStarter) {
        seedStarter.setDatePlanted(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        return "seedstartermng";
    }
```

Comment: The most reliable way to find out is to put a debug breakpoint in the constructor for `SeedStarter` and look at where it's being called. Spring is presumably just creating a new default instance because it can see that you want one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Spring MVC matches a controller method successfully and before it actually invokes it , it will resolve the method arguments based on argument type and its annotations. You can find all the supported type , annotations and the resolving rules from this [table](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

In your case , as `SeedStarter` does not have any annotations on it and its type is not the supported types , it will fall back to default as if `@ModelAttribute` is annotated on it. (Mentioned by the last rule in that table). And from `@ModelAttribute` [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args) , it will instantiate `SeedStarter` as follows :

> - From the model if already added by using Model.
> - From the HTTP session by using @SessionAttributes.
> - From a URI path variable passed through a
>     Converter (see the next example).
> - From the invocation of a default
>     constructor.
> - From the invocation of a “primary constructor” with
>     arguments that match to Servlet request parameters. Argument names are
>     determined through JavaBeans @ConstructorProperties or through
>     runtime-retained parameter names in the bytecode.